# When i open up a new application its already connected to a firebase account which is i don't have access to

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-assistant

When I open up a new application it's already connected to a Firebase account which I don't have access, is it possible to connect it to a new project using a new account and not with the one to which I lost access?

I tried to connect my new app with Firebase Realtime Database and it says connected already to a project that I created on my account which I already deleted.

Can you guys help me how to figure this out? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to connect it to a new project using a new account and not with the one to which I lost access?

For sure there is. You have to create a new Firebase project, download the google-services.json file and add it to your app folder inside your project. Right after that, you can try to connect to Firebase using the assistant as explained in the official documentation:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#assistant

In the URL above, you can also see at the top of the page, how you can manually add Firebase to your Android project. Which I personally recommend, because it offers more control on the setup workflow.

Comment: Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: yeah i followed it and figured it out thanks..